# Solving differential equation(Integrating factor)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation:
$$y(1+x-y^2)\frac{dy}{dx}=1$$
I have tried like this:
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=y+xy-y^3\\
\implies\frac{dx}{dy}-xy=(y-y^3)dy$$
$$I.F.=e^{-\int{ydy}}=e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}$$
$\therefore$ The solution is:
$$xe^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}=\int{(y-y^3)e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy}$$
Let, $y^2=2z$
$$\implies ydy=dz$$
\begin{align}
 xe^{-\frac{y^2}{2}} & =\int{e^{-z}dz}-2\int{ze^{-z}dz}\\
& = -e^{-z}+e^{-z}+2ze^{-z}\\
\end{align}
$$\therefore xe^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}=y^2e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}+c\\
\implies x=y^2+ce^{\frac{y^2}{2}}$$
But in my book the answer is:
$$ x=y^2+1+ce^{\frac{y^2}{2}}$$
Please tell where is my fault..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only problem was
$$xe^{-\frac{y^2}2}=-e^{-z}+\color{red}{2}e^{-z}+2ze^{-z}+c$$
Fix that lapse in application of the distributive law and all will be well.

Comment: I understood...thank you 

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a mistake when integrating the following,
$\int2ze^{-z}dz=-2e^{-z}-2ze^{-z}$

I tried to continue the steps and I got the same answer as your textbook, 
$x=1+2z+Ce^z=1+y^2+Ce^{y^2/2}$

Comment: Yes, thank you I understood 

Answer (score 0):

The solution of $$\frac{dx}{dy}+P(y)x=Q(y)~~~~(1)$$, the integrating factor id s $I=exp[\int P(y) dy]$. Then the solution of (1) is
$$x=I^{-1} \int I Q(y) dy+CI^{-1}~~~~(2)$$

You have missed $I^{-1}$ in the first place in  (2) in your solution. Do it again.